# How to make this select box in Javascript work so it enables another select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have a select box (company_selection) and that is generated in Javascript and I need it so when the option 'GW' is selected it enables the other select box (profile_selection) and allows you to choose the option 'ADickinson' when GW is selected in the other checkbox, however it's not working and I'm not sure why. Probably be something obvious :-)

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
formatAppSelect();

});
```

This is the method I have wrote to try get all this work. The variable companies are just the static options that I'm trying to get this to work with, they are the companies in the select box. The If statement is where the enabling is supposed to happen but when GW is selected in the select box nothing happens, what do I need to do? :) Don't think I need to post the HTML but I will if asked c:

```
     function formatAppSelect() {

var Companies = [{ Company: "GW" }, { Company: "TP" }];

var companyselectHTML = "<select name='select_company' id='select_company' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
                            "<option>None</option>";

var profileselectHTML = "<select name='select_profile' id='select_profile' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
                            "<option>None</option>";


for (var p = 0; p < Companies.length; p++) {
    companyselectHTML += "<option value='" + Companies[p].Company + "'>" + Companies[p].Company + "</option>";
}

profileselectHTML += "</select>";
$("#profile_selection").html(profileselectHTML);

profileselectHTML += "</select>";
$("#company_selection").html(companyselectHTML);

if (companyselectHTML == "GW") {

    profileselectHTML += "<option value='ADickinson'>ADickinson </option>";

}


 }
```

Comment: You need to attach to first select, a "change" event. On the change event, you can check the selected value and based on that change the options on the second select.

Comment: this is not how it works, for you to listen to any elements behavior on the page, you need to attach a event like `change` to it and add the if condition inside that to update your other drop-down list box

Comment: A change event huh? I'm not too familiar with that, do you think you could give some sort of example of what it'd look like/what I need to do. If that's not too much trouble of course Mr. Crossfire/dreamweiver :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were trying to achieve

**JQUERY CODE:**

`$(document).on('change', '#select_company', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "GW") $('#select_profile').append('<option value="ADickinson" selected="selected">ADickinson </option>');
});`

**LIVE DEMO @ JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/nZ8ma/6/

Since the Drop-down elements are added dynamically, you need to use delegated event handlers by attaching the event to the main root element `document` on your page.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: That's great, but it has the same problem (again my fault for not mentioning) as the other guys. The ADickinson doesn't disappear when another option is selected. What needs to be changed to fix this? ^^

Comment: @Shaun: thats not difficult, here you go  http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/nZ8ma/6/

Comment: Thanks, if I was to change it so that the option wasn't generated in the current profile but was instead an option like in the companies one, what would the option look like?

something like this?

"'<option value='" + User.Users + "</option>'");

I can't quite figure it out, if you can help me out with this I'll give you the accepted answer :-)

this is if I was wanting to load var Users = [{ User: "ADickinson" }]; instead of generating ADickinson

Comment: @Shaun: are you saying that you want the option on Profile drop-down to be created just like Company`s dropdown by mapping array values in loop ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be by a loop if there's an easier way, I just need the array value 'ADickinson' to appear in the select when GW is selected, instead of when GW is selected it generates ADickinson as an option. Is that complex to code?

Comment: well no , thats not difficult at all. you can define `ADickinson` in the array just the way you have define`d Company drop-down's` options. just make sure you place the array outside `$(document).ready(){...}`, so that its accessible anywhere in your js script code.

Comment: I've gave you the best answer for all your help, one last thing. What would the option value be inside the method you created? I've defined the loop like previously but I'm not sure what goes in the option value.

Comment: @Shaun: check this out ,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/nZ8ma/8/ . depending on which value you want to use for the new profile option you can use the appropriate index number of the array `Profiles` defined globally. going forward you can compare the `key` (Profile) and then set its `value` to the options which are getting added to Profiles drop-down dynamically.

Comment: I'm so confused here, I put the exact code into VisualStudio and it works but it creates two ADickinson's, so I tried putting it in my own jsFiddle and it works fine. What's going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57989/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-shaun).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#select_company").change(function(){//will be called when the select change of value
    if($(this).val() == "GW"){
        $("#select_profile").html("<option value='ADickinson'>ADickinson </option>");
    }else{ $("#select_profile").html(); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does generate an ADickinson when GW is selected. However if you select a different option the ADickinson doesn't disappear, and if you select GW again then another ADickinson appears so you have two ADickinson's in the select box. Maybe I should of mentioned this is my original post, sorry!

Comment: Do you think it would just be easier to declare the options like I have with the companies instead of just generating them? Cause on thoughts it seems like a simpler approach. Is that the case or would it be more difficult?

Comment: That fixed the generating lots of ADickinson's problem but when the company is changed to TP ADickinson is still there, is this something that can be solved in the code you have given or if I was writing the same method would I put a bit in that cleared the profile box of all values before it generated it :)

Comment: Nevermind, I realised anothe method would overwrite that one :)